# How does MVC/Razor engine find a view from a model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Given that we have a controller method returning a ViewResult with just a model object, how does the MVC or Razor engine go on to find which View to use, *given only the ViewResult*? 
e.g.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View( db.Persons.ToList());
    }
```

Edit: In other words, once this method has returned all the engine has to go on is a ViewResult. Anything it would use to find a view must be stored in this ViewResult.

Does it use the binding in the top of cshtml file?

```
    @model IEnumerable<Database.Models.Person>
```

Or does it use the string name of the model class and look it up via routing?

Or does it actually remember which controller called the View() method, and base it on that?

Or something else?

Sorry if this is an obvious question. I have read a lot of Stackoverflow questions and other pages and can't find which way is used... I see a lot of talk about how URLs are mapped to controllers but that's not the part I'm interested in.

Comment: It uses convention. If you don't specify the name of the view it looks in the `/Views/YourControllerName` folder for a `.cshtml` file that matches the method name (it also looks in the `Shared` folder if no match is found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That doesn't have anything to do with the Model. The `ViewEngine` searches for the View in the following locations.

- ~/Views/*{ControllerName}*/*{ActionName}*.cshtml
- ~/Views/*{ControllerName}*/*{ActionName}*.vbhtml
- ~/Views/*{ControllerName}*/*{ActionName}*.aspx
- ~/Views/*{ControllerName}*/*{ActionName}*.ascx

and

- ~/Views/Shared/*{ActionName}*.cshtml
- ~/Views/Shared/*{ActionName}*.vbhtml
- ~/Views/Shared/*{ActionName}*.aspx
- ~/Views/Shared/*{ActionName}*.ascx

The View name is the Action name by default, unless you specify the View name like this:

```
return View(model, "ViewName");
```

You can customize the search locations. You can read about that [here](http://theshravan.net/blog/configure-the-views-search-locations-in-asp-net-mvc/).

**UPDATE:**

The controller name and the action name will be stored in the `RouteData`. You can retrieve those from the `RouteData` like this:

```
var controllerName = RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
var actionName = RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

**UPDATE 2:**

`RouteData` is also a property of the `ControllerContext` class which the `ViewEngine` uses to find views. Look at the definition of the `FindView` method of the `IViewEngine` interface [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iviewengine.findview(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: OK, thanks. But how is the controller name stored in the ViewResult? I don't see anything in the ViewResult that could store the controller or it's name.

Comment: The RouteData will contain the controller name as a token with the name "controller".

Comment: @O'Rooney, Nathan answered your question. And I also include that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, but RouteData is a property on the Controller, not on ViewResult. I think I need to rewrite my question.

Comment: I guess the short answer is that ViewResult alone doesn't identify what to load, the ViewEngine also knows what controller it came from.

Comment: @O'Rooney, it looks like you didn't look at the link I added to my answer to the post about customizing search locations. Look at the second update in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I think I wasn't clear in my question. I was assuming that the engine figured out what to load from the ViewResult alone, but it obviously knows which controller is involved as well. I accepted your answer.